# Trying to make a player moveable sprite in pygame. Blank Screen

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

255I'm new to python/pygame. I'm trying to make a player moveable sprite but this code just brings up a black pygame window without a sprite. It shouldn't even be black because I wrote that the window should be filled with white. Please help me. Thank you.

```
 import pygame
 import os, sys
 import itertools
 import pygame
 import random

 pygame.init()
 screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,400))

 class killer(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.screen = screen
            self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png")
            self.image = self.image.convert()
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = (320, 400)
            self.dx = 0
            self.dy = 0
            self.x = self.rect.centerx
            self.y = self.rect.centery

    def update(self):
            self.CheckBounds()

    def checkBounds(self):
            screen = self.screen
            if self.x > screen.get_width():
                    self.x = screen.get_width()
            if self.x < 0:
                    self.x = 0

    def handle_keys(self):
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            dist = 1
            if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: # down key
                self.y += dist # move down
            elif key[pygame.K_UP]: # up key
                self.y -= dist # move up
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: # right key
                self.x += dist # move right
            elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]: # left key
                self.x -= dist # move left

    def draw(self,surface):
            surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


 ZK = killer()
 Clock = pygame.time.Clock()

 running = True
 while running:    
 for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit() 
        running = False

    ZK.handle_keys()

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    ZK.draw(screen) 
    pygame.display.update() 

    clock.tick(40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of errors:

1.) The indentation is broken
2.) `killer` never runs an initializer because you named it `_init_`, not `__init__`
3.) There's no variable called `clock` because you named it `Clock`
4.) When you close the window, an error will be raised because `pygame.key.get_pressed` will be called after the video system will be shut down (since you call `pygame.quit` before)

Fix this and your program will run fine.

Answer (score -1):

1.)
Line 11: You have

```
def _init_(self):
```

It should be

```
def __init__(self):
```

2.)
Line 65: You have

```
clock.tick(40)
```

It should be

```
Clock.tick(40)
```

Because you named your clock "Clock" at Line 50

```
 Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

~Just change these errors and you should be good to go!~